# ELLE Logo Designer

Tags: print-design, typography, logo, designers, type

Does anyone know who designed the ELLE magazine logo?

I have tried researching the original designer but can’t find the designer / artist who created the logo.

Comment: *Technically* it would probably be Firmin Didot since he designed the Didot typeface.. and the Elle logo is merely the Didot typeface with adjusted letter spacing.

Comment: So it’s just a type font rather than a specific designed logo?

Comment: It is just Didot, all uppercase, with extra spacing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that’s all I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

*Technically* it would probably be Firmin Didot since he designed the Didot typeface.

... and the Elle logo is merely the Didot typeface, all uppercase, with adjusted letter spacing.

I suppose Pierre Lazareva, and his wife Helene Gordon, could be credited as well since they created Elle magazine and it may have been one of them which specifically adjusted the spacing for the typeface.

.. all this information is readily available via simple web searches.